# Exception: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 )

Tags: jsp

i am trying to execute this query , but i am still having this exception telling me: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ), and i am not getting why this exception is arised .

```
String insert_doctor = "INSERT INTO doctor_info (user_id, fname, mname, lname, gender, DOB, reg_id, reg_date, contact, clinic_name, clinic_addr, city, state, country, clinic_phone,qualification,specialization,interests) VALUES (? ,? ,? ,? ,? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)";
PreparedStatement insert_data = conn.prepareStatement(insert_doctor);                   
                            String userid= Integer.toString(user_id);
                            insert_data.setString(1, userid);
                            insert_data.setString(2, fname);
                            insert_data.setString(3, mname);
                            insert_data.setString(4, lname);
                            insert_data.setString(5, gender);
                            insert_data.setString(6, dob);
                            insert_data.setString(7, reg_id);
                            insert_data.setString(8,reg_date);
                            insert_data.setString(9, contact);
                            insert_data.setString(10, clinic_name);
                            insert_data.setString(11, clinic_addr);
                            insert_data.setString(12, city);
                            insert_data.setString(13, state);
                            insert_data.setString(14, country);
                            insert_data.setString(15, clinic_phone);
                            insert_data.setString(16, qualification_s);
                            insert_data.setString(17, specialization_s);
                            insert_data.setString(18, interest_s);
```

Comment: On which line? Post the stack trace.